# Bootstrap carousel image size problems

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, image-gallery

I want to do an image gallery. I'm using this http://www.bootply.com/79859 but I have a problem because I don't know the image's sizes. The first image can be in 1800 x 400 the second 500x500 etc...

How can I do to set a max size and keep the image dimension 100% ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried playing with the slider div's `background-size` css property?
I would try using `background-size:cover` to make smaller images fit a larger div, and possibly `background-size:contain` for larger images. I think the attribute **contain** is what you're looking for - [here's a w3schools example.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=200px)

You can also set the height/width of the image like `background-size:10px 20px;` (height width). One thing to keep in mind with the images is the aspect ratio of height x width. I assume what you meant by image dimensions at 100% was keeping this ratio the same so the images did not skew.

Comment: Where I can put the `background-size:contain;` ? In the carousel-inner div ?

Comment: It appears the `.carousel-inner` class already has a background-size:cover, try updating that to be 'contain'

Comment: Here's a fiddle. Let's use this so we're both looking at the same thing. http://jsfiddle.net/clovola/dp9g7zzd/ I've included a few images with different sizes.

Comment: we need a max-height on the carousel-inner

Comment: Ok. I've updated the fiddle with the max-height like you mentioned. In case someone else wonders upon this question in the same situation. :)

Comment: Sorry forgot to 'set as base' in jsfiddle.

Comment: But there is a problem because the images are cut at the bottom

Comment: Just need to set the max-height of the image to the height of the carousel. Fiddle updated.